# Filter Entries within a page dynamically based on category

Tags: entries, categories

I'm creating a portfolio page, and I have a summary list of project entries displayed. At the top of the page, I've got a dropdown displaying a Category field. e.g. `craft.categories.group('industry')`

My question: Is it possible to display/filter entries of a particular category dynamically/immediately when a dropdown entry is selected (using only Twig)? Or do I have to use Javascript?

Sorry for this basic question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use some JavaScript, since all twig code is parsed on the server and sent to the browser as HTML.